# MQL4: ChartXYToTimePrice() on Y, used after ChartTimePriceToXY() does not produce the original price as a result

Tags: mql4, mql

I  came across these functions in MQL4 :

**`ChartTimePriceToXY()`**
and
**`ChartXYToTimePrice()`**

While I was doing one of my coding exercises, I tried to convert a price say 1.0850 to `X` and `Y` coordinates and convert the resultant `X` and `Y` coordinates back to the price, expecting to get back the same price. However, the price actually differs by a little bit.

Can anyone help me with this ?

```
   int xCoordEntrytest,yCoordEntrytest,temp1;
   datetime timetest;
   double pricetest;
   ChartTimePriceToXY(0,0,TimeCurrent(),1.0850,xCoordEntrytest,yCoordEntrytest);

   Print("Ynew= "+yCoordEntrytest);   
   Print("price used= 1.0850"); 

   ChartXYToTimePrice (0, xCoordEntrytest, yCoordEntrytest, temp1, timetest, pricetest);
   Print("priceoutput: "+pricetest);
```

[image: print compiled result]

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"`ChartXYToTimePrice()` on **`Y`**, used after `ChartTimePriceToXY()` **does not produce** the original price as a result ?"*

Obviously, the `Chart`-object has but an integer amount of "pixel-points".

```
PrintFormat( "Chart.Y_px %d", ChartGetInteger( ..., CHART_HEIGHT_PX, ... ) );
```

Even if the `Chart`-object has explicitly fixed **`CHART_PRICE_MIN`**, **`CHART_PRICE_MAX`** properties, which it need not, default state is to have the min/max floating, the conversion of a range of values "between" these min/max prices into a restricted amount of **`int`**-pixel values degrades the resolution.

That is fine for putting another object onto [X,Y]-pixel-grid, somewhere "near" a such translated price.

That is definitely a lossy transformation, so no one can expect to get the original, natively **`_Digits`**-deep resolution in the `PriceDOMAIN`, once any of the pixel-grid related `Y` gets transformed back from `int` towards the **`double`** in the `PriceDOMAIN`.

To test this, just :

```
double P_from_Y,
       P_from_Y_minus1,
       P_from_Y_plus1;

ChartXYToTimePrice( thisCHART,
                    xCoordEntrytest, yCoordEntrytest+1,
                    thisWINDOW,
                    timetest, 
                    P_from_Y_plus1
                    );

ChartXYToTimePrice( thisCHART,
                    xCoordEntrytest, yCoordEntrytest,
                    thisWINDOW,
                    timetest, 
                    P_from_Y
                    );

ChartXYToTimePrice( thisCHART,
                    xCoordEntrytest, yCoordEntrytest-1,
                    thisWINDOW,
                    timetest, 
                    P_from_Y_minus1
                    );

PrintFormat( "[Y-1=%5d]-to-Price %12.6f",
             ( yCoordEntrytest - 1 ),
             P_from_Y_minus1
             );
PrintFormat( "[Y+0=%5d]-to-Price %12.6f",
             ( yCoordEntrytest ),
             P_from_Y
             );
PrintFormat( "[Y+1=%5d]-to-Price %12.6f",
             ( yCoordEntrytest + 1 ),
             P_from_Y_plus1
             );
```